# Using Coefficients without Knowing the Estimation Method

Tags: regression, estimation, least-squares, bias

This is a rather basic question, and I assume the answer is no, but I have a list of variables and coefficients associated with a linear regression:

```
 height                 .02
 weight                 .33
 age                    .0001
 maritalstatus_binary   .025
```

Suppose I know the coefficients and I know the type of regression, but not the method that was used to calculate the coefficients. What is the **worst** that can happen by taking this regression and using it on the same data for the same purpose without knowing the method of estimation?

Comment: Can you please explain exactly what information you have & don't have (in the two cases)?

Comment: @scortchi Do the changes help? It's really more of a question about what else should be known in these circumstances. The first where we only know the coefficients, the second where we know the coefficients and the regression but now how it was produced.

Comment: Are you really asking the use of a piece of paper you found blowing around in the street with "Regression Coefficients" written on it followed by some numbers? Surely there's more context.

Comment: @Scortchi See updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. If your goal is merely prediction than you're probably taking the coefficients as is, as long as you have reason to believe that the underlying sample wasn't biased. On the other hand, if your goal is understanding then the standard is higher. For instance, you need to know the degree to which the coefficients are collinear. If the coefficients are collinear it decreases your confidence in your interpretation of the model.

However, the biggest downside to being limited to the information you have provided is that you won't be able to produce a prediction interval for your predictions. In order to calculate the prediction interval you would need one of two things. Either, the ability to calculate the standard errors along with the ability to do [some goodness of fit evaluation](http://people.duke.edu/~rnau/testing.htm). Or you would need access to the underlying data and the ability to [bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)) the standard errors.